# rails validation,How to check field having value in range of other field

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-3, validation, range

I got two fields:

validates :bhp

validates :ps

Now if the value of :bhp is 80,

then value of :ps should be within a range +-10 of :bhp for eg. [70..90] in here.

And vice-versa should also work

Answer (score 0):

You can use custom validator.

Something like this:

```
validate :keep_ps_in_range_of_bhp

def keep_ps_in_range_of_bhp
  range = 10
  unless (bhp-ps).abs <= range
    errors.add(:ps, "should be in range +-#{range} of bhp")
  end
end
```

Similar way you can add validator for the opposite case, but it makes sense only if you don't allow to change both this values (but even in this case I don't sure that it is really good approach).

Comment: Too complicated! Use `(bhp-ps).abs <= range`.

Comment: Pls if you can help, one more case in there, if user has provide a value in one field is it possible to set value during validation in another field by using conversion formula. For eg. conversion formula for bhp is bhp = ps/1.01387 And if user has provide with both values, then to check if they are same as conversion formula.